# VBA vlookup data from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Trying to vlookup from another workbook(its name I search in a certain folder upfront). I got error message `Unable to get Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class`.
I added watches to see if I have meaningful variables.
Tried to put `Thisworkbook.` in front of `sh_main` but it does't work either. I don't know what do I do wrongly, any help highly appreciated!

```
Sub Actual_inventory()

Assignments1
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, i As Integer
Dim col_unrestricted As String
Dim range_temp2 As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
directory = "C:\Users\marcellh\Documents\Reports\Actual\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")


Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

'converts column A to number format:
Range("A:A").Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With

'searches column "unrestricted":
Set range_temp2 = Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(1).Cells.Find("unrestricted")
col_unrestricted = range_temp2.Column
'---

i = first_data_set


Do While sh_main.Cells(i, col_color).Value <> ""

'vlookups based on old gmid, iferror then "":
sh_main.Cells(i, col_inventory_old_gmid).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sh_main.Cells(i, col_old_gmid_code).Value, Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(1).Range("A:L"), col_unrestricted, False)
If IsError(sh_main.Cells(i, col_inventory_old_gmid).Value) Then
    sh_main.Cells(i, col_inventory_old_gmid).Value = ""
End If

'vlookups based on new gmid, iferror then "":
sh_main.Cells(i, col_inventory_new_gmid).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sh_main.Cells(i, col_new_gmid_code).Value, Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(1).Range("A:L"), col_unrestricted, False)
If IsError(sh_main.Cells(i, col_inventory_new_gmid).Value) Then
    sh_main.Cells(i, col_inventory_new_gmid).Value = ""
End If

i = i + 1
Loop


Workbooks(fileName).Close

fileName = Dir()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Actual inventory has been loaded successfully"


End Sub
```

This is where the macro stucks with the error message:
[image]

Comment: "sh_main" is worksheet type (Assignment1 gives him value)

Comment: I tried to make the same formula and it seems to be working fine - only if the value is not found in the searched range it actually still returns the error that you have - are you sure the value is present in there?

Comment: oh, so banal. Yes, that was the problem, I had put and Error handler, now works fine. Many thanks for your help !!

Comment: On Error Resume Next should never be used but on one line, then cancelled  by On Error Goto 0. Many VBA newbies find it convenient to avoid error messages by using this line on a global scope. Alas, so deceitful.

Comment: I had put Application.Vlookup into a variable which allows me to check iferror(variable) in advance of the actual usage. I am not sure it applies the fastest calculation method behind.

Comment: Make an answer! Mark it correct! Get your internet points!